# ¿Como crear sequences en MariaDB Server?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Dentro de gestores de bases de datos como lo son:

1. Oracle
2. PostgreSQL
3. SQL Server

Tenemos la posibilidad de crear secuencias, que nos ayudan por ejemplo a generar la llave auto incremental que distinga cada uno de los registros de una tabla en una base de datos, como alternativa a el uso de `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Por ejemplo en **PostgreSQL**, lo hacemos del modo siguiente

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Por ejemplo en **SQL Server** lo podemos lograr del modo siguiente

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id as BIGINT
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Y el **Oracle 11g** por ejemplo lo podemos hacer del modo siguiente

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

> A la `sequence` la indicamos un nombre, posteriormente la indicamos el
>   valor entero en el que va a comenzar y finalmente el valor con el que
>   se va a ir incrementando el valor inicial.
>
> Si por ejemplo deseamos ahora usar ese valor en un registro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mariaDB desde la versión 10.3 existe la posibilidad de forma nativa de utilizar la creación de sequences; a través del siguiente ejemplo se puede observar como lograrlo

**Primero vamos a crear la tabla sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Si por ejemplo queremos ver la estructura de la tabla id, recién creada; basta con ejecutar lo siguiente en la consola

```
MariaDB [blog]> describe id;
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| next_not_cached_value | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| minimum_value         | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| maximum_value         | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_value           | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| increment             | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cache_size            | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cycle_option          | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cycle_count           | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

De la anterior tabla podemos notar detalles importantes como el hecho de que el valor numérico por defecto creado es de tipo `BIGINT`

De modo tal que como le hemos indicado que va a iniciar la numeración en 1 y en uno mas se va a ir incrementando nos permite generar al número progresivo que puede estar asociado como llave primaria a una tabla

Vamos entonces a crear una nueva tabla de ejemplo en el gestor mariaDB

```
MariaDB [blog]> CREATE TABLE demo(
    -> id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    -> name VARCHAR(30),
    -> PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Finalmente a diferencia de cuando se declara una `primary key` de tipo `auto_increment` que no es necesario declararla en la sentencia `insert`, cuando hacemos uso de una sequence si es necesario escribir el nombre de la columna; como el ejemplo siguiente

```
MariaDB [blog]> INSERT INTO demo(id, name)
    -> VALUES
    -> (NEXT VALUE FOR id, 'alfa');
```

Como se puede observar de la sentencia anterior, para insertar el valor dinámico que genera la sequence, invocamos el nombre de la misma a través de `NEXT VALUE FOR` y al final el nombre de la sequence `id`

Finalmente para poder visualizar el resultado de nuestra sentencia anterior, ejecutamos un `SELECT` regular sobre la tabla y obtenemos lo siguiente

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT * FROM demo;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | alfa |
+----+------+
```

**Configuraciones extra:**

> Opcionalmente le puedes configurar los siguientes parametros a una
>   sequence dentro del gestor mariaDB:

1. `minvalue` = Puedes establecerlo 1
2. `maxvalue` = Dependiendo del tipo de dato que eligas si es `INT` o `BIGINT` debes revisar para colocar un tope que respete los límites de esos tipos de datos
3. `Cycle` = Por defecto tiene la opción no cycle, de lo contrario, una vez que el valor mínimo arranque y se llegue al tope máximo, el contador se va a reiniciar y empezará la numeración de nuevo **(siempre que por el límite del tipo de dato sea posible)**