# AUTI INCREMENT en una una tabla de oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Buenas quiero crear una tabla en un squema de oracle que se llama CA:

```
CREATE TABLE  PDT_CONCEPTOS(
ID INT(8) NOT NULL,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
CODIGO_PDT VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
CODIGO_DB VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,  
DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(250)NOT NULL,  
PERTENECE VARCHAR(150)NOT NULL,  
DB_TABLA VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY(ID)  
 );
```

lo que quiero es que mi ID sea auto incrementable y que se cree en el schema CA espero su ayuda gracias

Comment: Investiga sobre el uso de sequences

Comment: Revisa la parte de esta pregunta ahí muestro cómo hacer una secuencia en oracle ya después solo debes invocarla

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197399/como-crear-sequences-en-mariadb-server

Comment: ok gracias por la informacion

Comment: Si no te queda avísame y en un momento te hago una respuesta

Comment: No me funciono pero creo la tabla creo q lo hice mal

Comment: Dame unos minutos y te respondo con un ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un secuencia de este modo, en la cual indicas el nombre que en este caso será `id` que empieza en 1 y por cada vuelta se incrementa en 1:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Posterior tenemos una tabla similar a la siguiente, donde como puedes observar la columna de `PRIMARY KEY` se llama igual que la secuencia que creamos arriba

```
CREATE TABLE persons(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Ahora procedemos a realizar una inserción del modo siguiente, donde para invocar la secuencia, se hace del modo siguiente: `id.NEXTVAL` que es el nombre de la sequence punto y el método `NEXTVAL`

```
INSERT INTO persons(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (id.NEXTVAL, 'alfreds', 'peaces');
```